# Counting efficiently pairs of strings, which together contain all the vowels

Tags: string

I have solved the following question but still need to improve the performance:

> I have N words with me. For each valid i, word i is described by a
>   string Di containing only lowercase vowels, i.e. characters 'a', 'e',
>   'i', 'o', 'u'.
>
> What is the total number of (unordered) pairs of words such that when
>   concatenated, they contain all the vowels?

My C++ code works using a bit array to represent the vowels present in a word.  Then I check all pairs of strings by combining their bit array looking if all the vowel bits are set.  I do this by comparing the combination to a bit array  'complete' which has all bits set corresponding to the vowels:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int t;
  cin>>t;      // number of different test cases
  while(t--)
  {
    int n;         // number of strings 
    cin>>n;

    int con_s[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      string s;
      cin>>s;
      con_s[i]=0;      // converting vowels present in string into a bit array 
      for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++)
      {
        con_s[i] = con_s[i] | (1<<(s[j]-'a'));
      }
    }
    int complete = 0; // bit array corresponding to all possible vowels 
    complete = (1<<('a'-'a')) | (1<<('e'-'a')) | (1<<('i'-'a')) | (1<<('o'-'a')) | (1<<('u'-'a'));
    // cout<<complete;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)        // check the pairs
    {
      for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
      {
        if((con_s[i] | con_s[j])==complete)count++;
      }
    }
    cout<<count<<"\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Although the bit array use very fast bit manipulation, it appears that my algorithm is not efficient enough when having larger set of input strings.  Can anyone suggest an efficient solution ?

**Additional information**

Test Case:

```
Input:
   1
   3
   aaooaoaooa
   uiieieiieieuuu
   aeioooeeiiaiei

Result: 2
```

Explanation:
The 2 pairs (1 and 2) and (2 and 3) contain all 5 vowels when concatenated, while pair (1 and 3) do not match the criteria since the concatenation does not contain 'u'. Hence the result is 2.

Constraints:

```
1≤T≤1,000
1≤N≤105
1≤|Di|≤1,000 for each valid i
the sum of all |D_i| over all test cases does not exceed 3⋅107
```

Comment: This looks like Hackerrank / Codechef / Homework. Please share the code you did and explain what is wrong. Relabel your question accordingly. Do not post c++ code in python and vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54970876/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have posted my code(C++).

Comment: `vector<string> v; long long  con_s[n];` -- You do realize that `long long con_s[n]` is not valid C++?  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime variable such as `n`.  But saying that, right before that line, you use `std::vector`.  So why didn't you use it on the second line also, i.e. `std::vector<long long> con_s(n);`?

Comment: How much efficientness is "efficient enough"? For example, do you want to process 100,000 strings in 1 second on modern processer using only one thread?

Comment: @DoeDoe -- Once you start to write a nested loop, you are in danger of the code not being efficient enough.  These types of questions are designed so that naive solutions such as nested `for` loops will almost always fail, and the "real" solution is to use some sort of data structure or dynamic programming technique.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am sure you are right... but I have no clue how to optimize upon this, can you suggest a solution

Comment: @MikeCAT I have put my contraints...please suggest a solution... the help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, that is part of the test.  You need to do research on what type of structure can efficiently be used.  Again, these tests look on the surface as just pure programming tests, but that is not the case -- they are specifically designed so that you put more thought into how to approach the problem.

Comment: @DoeDoe Hint: You won't need to distinguish between strings having the same set of vowels.

Comment: @DoeDoe The comment section is for comments, not answers.  I am commenting on the fact that naive solutions do not work on these "Hackerrank" or similar sites, and that **you** need find a different approach.  The whole purpose of those sites is for you to do the research, and not find someone to do the research for you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no one needs to do the research for me, if you know how to solve the solution, you post it, that's it. Why do discussions take place after competitions ?. You are supposed to get an idea of the solution...every question posted n the forum can be answered with a simple...."try a different apporach"..but it doesnt help!

Comment: You seem to be fixated on my comments, but totally oblivious as to why you're being downvoted by multiple people (and two votes away from the question being closed).  No one should post answers to this problem here, since that would be considered cheating and totally defeating the purpose of those other sites (copy and paste the answer from here to there).

Comment: Also, when we say "try a different approach", it doesn't mean to start writing code immediately.  Look at the problem given -- is there a way to represent the strings differently, arrange or group them differently, etc.  Is there a way to use an efficient data structure such as a hash table or map to cut down the number of iterations, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have made myself pretty clear... people might misunderstand me...but I am lookig for a better logic... not looking for answers... also I have put my head to it for the past day and found that I should post it here and might try and get some ideas

Comment: Your bitmap approach is great. But you loose a lot of energy by putting one bitmap per string in a large array and do all these combinations. So keeping your great idea and thinking slightly differently (map of bitmaps) in order to avoid all these many unnecessary combinations, quickly leads to a very efficient solution (efficiency can be proven mathematically).

Comment: I'd suggest to reword the question in order to replace "My code is not optimised enough" (which misleadingly give the impression that you are looking for micro-optimisations), to something like:  "My algorithm is not good enough to process large number of input strings", so that the reader can quickly understand the real nature of this interesting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a very large number of strings.  Your algorithm will compare all the strings between them, and thats a terrible number of iterations.

## Radical improvement:

### New approach

Build a map that associates a string of ordered unique vowels (e.g. "ae") to a list of all the string found that contains exactly these unique vowels, whatever the number of repetition and the order. For example:

```
ao -> aaooaoaooa, aoa, aaooaaooooooo  (3 words)
uie -> uiieieiieieuuu, uuuuiiiieeee   (2 words)
aeio -> aeioooeeiiaiei                (1 word)
```

Of course, that's a lot of strings, so in your code, you would use your bitmap rather than the string of ordered unique vowels.  Also note that you don't want to produce the list of combined string, but only their count.  So you don't need the list of all string occurenes, but just to maintain the count of strings matching the bitmap:

```
16385 -> 3 
1048848 -> 2
16657 -> 1
```

Then look at the winning combinations between the mapping existing indexes, like you did it. For a large list of strings, you would have a much smaller list of mapping indexes, so that would be a significant improvement.

For each winning combination take the size of the first list of strings time the size of the second list of strings to increase your count.

```
16385 1048848 is complete -> 3 x 2 = 6 combinations
1048848 16657 is complete -> 2 x 1 = 2 combinations 
                                    ---
                                     8 potential combinations
```

### What's the improvement ?

These combinations were found by analysing 3x2 bitmaps, rather than looking at 6x5 bitmaps corresponding to the unique strings.  A gain by a significant order of magnitude if you have larger number of strings.

To be more general, as you have 5 wovels and there must be at least one, you can have only a maximum of `2<<5-1` so 31 different bitmaps and therefore a maximum of C(31,2) that's 465 <strike>`31*30` that's 930</strike> combinations to check whether you have 100 strings or 10 million strings as input.  Would I be correct to state that it's roughly  O(n) ?

Possible implementation:

```
map<int, int> mymap; 
int n;
cin>>n;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int bm=0;
    for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++)
        bm |= (1<<(s[j]-'a'));
    mymap[bm]++;
}
int complete = (1<<('a'-'a')) | (1<<('e'-'a')) | (1<<('i'-'a')) | (1<<('o'-'a')) | (1<<('u'-'a'));
int count = 0;
int comparisons = 0; 
for (auto i=mymap.begin(); i!=mymap.end(); i++)  {
    auto j=i; 
    for(++j;j!=mymap.end();j++) {
        comparisons++; 
        if((i->first | j->first)==complete) {
            count += i->second * j->second; 
            cout << i->first <<" "<<j->first<<" :"<<i->second<<" "<<j->second<<endl;
        }
    }
}
auto special = mymap.find(complete);  // special case: all strings having all letters
if (special!=mymap.end()) {           // can be combined with themselves as well
    count += special->second * (special->second -1) / 2; 
}
cout<<"Result: "<<count<<" (found in "<<comparisons<<" comparisons)\n";
```

[Online demo with 4 examples](https://ideone.com/1anawY) (only strings with all letters, your initial example, my example above, and an example with couple of more strings)

Comment: Man, I so appreciate your solution but It does not work if the words individually contain all the vowels. Do you know a way around that ?

Comment: can you check on test cases like 3 :- aieoeiu, aiueoe, u etc.

Comment: @DoeDoe Indeed!  The strings of mymap[complete] could be combined between themselves.  In this case you'd need to add 'mymap[complete]*(mymap[complete]-1)/2'

Comment: @DoeDoe I've edited the answer accordingly and updated the online demo

Comment: @Cristophe, you're a legend mate!. Thanks so much!. I;ve learnt a new trick today, thanks to you : )

Comment: @DoeDoe Thanks ! I'm glad that it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer then.  On my part, I really enjoyed helping to improve your solution, and be aware that such bitmaps may also be used to solve real world pattern matching problems :-)